# How to solve OutOfMemoryError ?

Tags: android-emulator

I just published an app on Google play store namely " Bad Piggies Full Guide " . Today one user posted an error and the error says that :

"OutOfMemoryError 
in Bitmap.nativeCreate()"

The Full Stack Traces Are :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ashutos.cool/com.ashutos.cool.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #414: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2705)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #414: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1656)
at com.ashutos.cool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
... 27 more
```

Can Anyone Solve this error please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to solve OutOfMemoryError in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581456/how-to-solve-outofmemoryerror-in-android)

Comment: Doesn't this  hint anything? `bitmap size exceeds VM budget` The image is too big to fit in the available RAM.

Comment: The VM was running out of memory due to large size image so only you getting this error